# How to use ` Files.walk` and early termination

Tags: java, performance, file, navigation

I have a piece of code similar to this

```
Optional<Path> confFile = Files.walk(Paths.get("./")) // traverse and visit ...
              .filter(p -> p.getFileName().endsWith("configuration.properties")) // search config file
```

I would like the stream to end as soon as i find any such file and not to continue until it traverse all the subfolders.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called `findFirst`:

```
Optional<Path> confFile = Files.walk(Paths.get("./"))
                            .filter(p -> p.getFileName().endsWith("configuration.properties"))
                            .findFirst()
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--):

> Returns an Optional describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty. If the stream has no encounter order, then any element may be returned.
>
> This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.

"Short-circuiting" means:

> A terminal operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may terminate in finite time.

Note that it doesn't matter that `filter` is not short circuiting, because `filter` is lazy, so it will only process as many paths as `findFirst` needs it to.